# Problemas com a biblioteca com Python

Tags: python, biblioteca

Alguém pode me afirmar que a biblioteca "comtypes.client" é só do Windows? se sim, por favor me digam alguma biblioteca semelhante(Que sirva pra mesma coisa) pro Linux(ubuntu) obrigado.

Comment: A [documentação](https://pypi.org/project/comtypes/) dela já diz: *It works on Windows, 64-bit Windows, and Windows CE.* Para dizer uma semelhante, precisamos saber o que ela faz, ou o que está utilizando da biblioteca.

Comment: Sim, apenas windows. Como já diz na [documentação](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/) ela é baseada no [módulo ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) então talvez seja este que procura.

Comment: pelo que pude ler em https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/157, uma versão atualizada já instala no Linux sem problemas

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: @tetri instalar, instala, mas não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa biblioteca `comtypes` é um pacote leve para acesso ao COM no python, permitindo criar e registrar ou acessar interfaces COM no seu script.

COM significa [Component Object Model](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), e é uma **plataforma da Microsoft** para componentes de software lançada em 1993.

O uso dela é permitir a comunicação entre processos Windows e a criação dinâmica de objetos em qualquer linguagem de programação que suporte a tecnologia. O seu uso **não faz sentido algum no linux**, uma vez que no linux não existem objetos COM. Portanto essa biblioteca não funciona no linux, e não existe nenhuma outra biblioteca para acesso a COM que funcione, pois esses objetos não existem no linux.

Nas distribuições linux são usadas outras tecnologias para comunicação entre processos, como por exemplo o DBus.

Seria legal se passasse para nós o que queria fazer com essa biblioteca, assim podemos recomendar uma forma alternativa de fazer.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela atenção e educação. eu to criando um assistente virtual em python(para um projeto da minha escola) e a minha intenção era que houvesse interação com a maquina, a biblioteca que eu queria a  Biblioteca para transcrever texto em fala, mas que funcione no ubuntu.

Comment: No ubuntu tem o espeak, muito simples de usar:  `sudo apt install espeak` e em seguida no python, crie uma variável `frase` com o que quer falar e chame `subprocess.call(['espeak', '-v', 'pt', frase.encode('utf-8')])`. Se tiver dúvidas, sugiro abrir nova pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que minha resposta atende a sua pergunta @kingarthur , se achar que é o caso, sugiro marcá-la como aceita para fechar a pergunta.